# Method to combine quantile regression forecasts

Tags: python, neural-network, regression, data-science, quantile-regression

I am predicting electricity usage for customers which is highly skewed. Regular regression models did not fit well due to skewed distribution, hence I tried quantile regression. I'm obtaining the models for 0.1, 05 and 0.9 quantiles. So I have 3 set of predictions for the three models optimized at the quantiles specified above. All the three models perform very well for the quantiles optimized but the performance decreases for other quantiles as one would expect. Regular averaging would give equal weights to all three model outputs and hence does not represent true distribution. Can anyone suggest what would be the best method for model averaging for quantile regression method?

Comment: Why not increase the resolution of quantiles, e.g., to 5%, 10%, 15%, ..., 95%? This way, you will obtain a rather fine approximation of the predictive distribution, from which you can calculate an approximate expected value.

Comment: @InonPeled - Yes you are right, I can do that. The quantiles I have mentioned is purely for example purpose. The question still would be what would be the best way to weighted average these predictions

Comment: You regress quantiles of the CDF, right? If you are satisfied with the resulting approximation of the CDF (e.g., after linearly interpolating each pair of consecutive quantiles), then you now have a distribution, just calculate from it the expected value as for any distribution, be it discrete or continuous.

Comment: @InonPeled - How can I score for the unknown data as I would not know the quantiles they would belong to?